# Python random non alphabetical character

Tags: python, random, alphabetical

I am new to python so i am not sure how this would work out.
Anyhow, I would like to know how to pick a random non alphabetical character/symbol and simply print it.
Just as an example it will randomly pick "æ"

Thanks!

Comment: Define "alphabetical". Is 'Я' alphabetical? It's in the Cyrillic alphabet. How about '' (not to be confused with 'T')?

Comment: Use the chr function on a randomly generated number in the required ascii characters range.

Comment: Alphabetical any ascii chars from a-z and A-Z

Comment: @EugeneSh. i tried that but it prints out something similar to '\u195d'.. is there a way to convert it to a "readable" character?

Comment: It is readable in python 3.

Comment: This character is not ASCII, it is unicode. If can remain in the 0-255 range in order not to get this (if it is acceptable)

Comment: @simonzack readable for a human beeing .-.

Comment: @user3802921 Give it a try, fellow human being.

Comment: as @simonzack mentioned, python 3 is capable of displaying unicode characters

Comment: @EugeneSh. but my question is "how do i display it as unicode?"

Comment: With `print`. What's the problem? Show us the code you've tried, and we'll have more to say.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker basically i want to print out the symbol and nothing like '\u...'. I've googled quite a while but i havent found a working method yet.

Comment: Again, `print` works just fine. There's nothing wrong with your Python inerpreter. SHOW US CODE and we can see what you're doing wrong, otherwise quit wasting our time.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker print('\u0220') and print(u'\u0220') error with "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0220' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>"

Comment: `print u"\x0220"` prints a sort of N-looking thing with a long right leg on my terminal. Note that you do need to specify that the string is Unicode if you're using Python  2. In Python 3, `print("\u0220")` is sufficient. If it's not showing up on your screen, that might be an OS/terminal/font kind of problem. You might also have a `setdefaultencoding` problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print characters from a given sequence, you can use this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import random

seq=['☺', '☹', '♡', '♥', '❀', '❃']

for i in range(20):
    print random.choice(seq),
```

The output is for example:

```
☹ ♥ ❀ ❀ ❀ ❃ ☺ ♡ ♡ ❃ ❀ ❀ ☺ ☺ ♡ ❃ ♡ ♡ ❃ ❀
```

Note the `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-`  which tells python that this file is encoded in utf8.

Or this:

```
for i in range(8592, 8602):
    print unichr(i),
```

which gives me

```
← ↑ → ↓ ↔ ↕ ↖ ↗ ↘ ↙
```

This works quite fine for me.

But note: Your console has to support unicode, and the font has to contain the glyphs for your character. I use Linux, may be, Windows has some problems with unicode?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Seems like anything unicode related errors with UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character, vanilla Windows CMD prints out the char with the echo command though.. this is weird

Comment: I might have suspected Windows. It probably defaults to CP1251 encoding instead of UTF8 or something.

Comment: Just a remark: As you can see from my print statements, I'm still using Python 2.Xx

Answer (score 0):

Okay so print actually hasn't had any problems it was Python all along.
I had to update, i had v 3.3